# Fastest way to search list for an element that begins with a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, search

What is the fastest way to search a list whether or not it has an element that begins with a specified string, and then return the index of the element if it's found.

Something like:

```
mylist=['one','two','three','four']
mystring='thr'
```

It should return `2`.

Comment: The fastest way is to not use Python for this task. So would reasonably fast and readable be enough?

Comment: How many times will you be searching vs. how often the list is changed?

Comment: Show what you have and we'll tell you if it can be improved. Better yet: if you have working code, ask on [codereview.se] as they specialize in improving working code, not fixing broken code as is done here.

Comment: @timget et all, only 1 time search, the list won't be changed, i would like the best method for python, i dont use other languages, so the reasonably fastest method that is available for python3.x would satisfy, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get better than O(n) complexity here, but generally speaking if you are after pure speed then don't even use Python.

The canonical Python solution I would propose is to use a memory efficient generator and call `next` on it once.

```
>>> mylist = ['one','two','three','four']
>>> mystring = 'thr'
>>> next(index for index, item in enumerate(mylist) if item.startswith('thr'))
2
```

By default, this will give you a `StopIteration` exception if the condition is never satisfied. You can provide a second argument to `next` if you want a  fallback-value.

Comment: ＋1 for ignoring the poorly constrained "fastest" request, and providing most Pythonic instead.

Comment: by default it raises stopiteration without 2nd arg

Answer (score 0):

`indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(mylist) if s.startswith('thr')]`
Enumerate is slightly faster

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do more than a single search, you can organize the list in a way to get better than O(n) execution time for each search. Obviously if you're only doing a single search the overhead of reorganizing the list will be prohibitive.

```
import bisect
mylist.sort()
n = bisect.bisect_left(mylist, mystring)
if n >= len(mylist) or not mylist[n].startswith(mystring):
    print('not found')
```

If you need to preserve the original order it's only a little more complicated.

```
mysorted = sorted((s,i) for i,s in enumerate(mylist))
n = bisect.bisect_left(mysorted, (mystring, 0))
if n >= len(mysorted) or not mysorted[n][0].startswith(mystring):
    print('not found')
else:
    n = mysorted[n][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just running a counter should do you fine

```
i = 0
mylist = ['one','two','three','four']
mystring = 'thr'
for x in mylist:
    if mystring in x:
       i = i + 1
       print (i)
    else:
       i = i + 1
```

Although this will print '3' and not '2'.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Try changing `mystring = 'hr'`. It does not need to begin with for using `in` function.

Answer (score -1):

```
mystring='thr'
[n for (n,item) in enumerate(mylist) if item.startswith(mystring)][0]
Out: 2
```